# Why does the sine wave graph gets inverted when we put $t=0$ in $A\sin(wt-kx)$ and what does it signify?

Tags: waves

I was studying standing waves today and the teacher took a string attached to a fixed end then waves are produced (of equation $Asin(\omega t-kx)$ )on the string.
and then he told us that the reflected wave equation will be $-Asin(\omega t+kx)$
Then he put the value of $t=0$, in both equations and the values he got were $-Asin(kx)$ for the produced wave and for reflected wave it was $-Asin(kx)$ and thus he concluded that at T=0, the waves would interfere and give a amplitude of $-2Asin(kx)$
I didn't understand it.
i want to know the physical significance of putting $t=0$.

Comment: It means the wave is moving to the right.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, there is no physical meaning, since the answer is coordinate dependent (when is $t=0$?), and (write this down): Physics does not depend on your coordinate system.

But maybe, in this case (with $A=1$, since $A$ doesn't matter) the sum of waves is:

$$ \sin(-kx) + \sin(+kx) = -\sin(kx) + \sin(kx) = 0 $$

which means you have chosen a coordinate system such that at $t=0$, the wave is in a state of maximum kinetic energy and minimum potential energy.

Had you not made this choice, you would write the equations with an arbitrary phase ($\phi$) offset:

$$ \psi_+(x, t) = A\sin(kx-\omega t + \phi) $$
$$ \psi_-(x, t) = A\sin(-kx-\omega t + \phi) $$

and you could find a value of $t$ where those add to zero.

Finally: I am a little sus, since phase is usually written:

$$ \phi(x, t) = kx-\omega t = -(\omega t - kx)$$

and real waves are more naturally written as:

$$ \cos(kx-\omega t) $$

There's nothing wrong with sine, but it's got a 90 degree phase offset from
"the usual", and sign flip on the phase is another 180 degree offset...which will just cause algebraic overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a $1$D transverse sin wave traveling down a string. How would you mathematically describe it? You must find a function $y = f(x,t)$ that gives the height $y$ for each point $x$ and each time $t$.

Let us say the wave travels in the $+x$ direction with velocity $v$, and its amplitude is $A$.

If you look at any fixed point $x_0$, that point goes up and down sinusoidally. Let us suppose that the motion repeats with frequency $2\pi \omega$.

Finally, let us say that at time $t=0$, the point at $x=0$ is at height $y=0$ and is heading upward.

We have supposed enough things that we can figure out the function $f$.

---

Let us look at the motion of the point $x=0$. We can get a simplified version of the function $f(x,t)$, which we will call $f_{x=0}$.

$$f_{x=0}(t) = f(0,t)$$

We know that the height at this point is a sinusoidal function with amplitude A, and frequency $2\pi \omega$. At $t=0$, $y=0$ and is heading up. The function that satisfies all this is

$$y = Asin(\omega t)$$

Other points will also be going up and down sinusoidally. Not exactly the same function as $f_{x=0}(t)$. But at any time, a point $x$ will have a height $y = f(x,t) = Asin(\omega t + \theta_x)$ for some $\theta_x$. Each point will have its own value $\theta_x$. We have to figure out what $\theta_x$ is for each $x$.

---

Let us look at some point $x = 0$ at time $t_0$. The height is some value $y = Asin(\omega t_0)$.

The wave travels. At some later time $t_0 + \Delta t$, the wave will have arrived at $x = v\Delta t$. That point will have the same height $y = Asin(\omega (t_0 + \Delta t) + \theta_x)$.

But this is also $y = Asin(\omega t_0)$.

So $\omega t_0 = \omega (t_0 + \Delta t) + \theta_x$

$\theta_x = -\omega \Delta t = -\omega x/v$

And

$$y = Asin(\omega t -(\omega/v)x)$$

Defining $k = \omega / v$, we have

$$y = Asin(\omega t-kx)$$

---

This tells you mathematically why there is a -k. But it also tells you physically.

Here is a graph of $y = f(x,t)$ at $t=0$. You can see it is $y = Asin(-kx) = -Asin(kx)$. You can see this is the right function. As the wave travels to the right, the point at $0$ $y$ goes up.

Also think about the point on the wave at $y=0$. For this point, $y = Asin(0)$. That is, $\omega t-kx = 0$. Where does this point go as $t$ get bigger? The equation tells you that it travels to where $x$ is bigger.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

At time T=0 both the waves Asin(wt-kx) and it's reflected wave both represent same wave,which are in same phase, when they are superimposed to each other they form a constructive interference and their amplitude is added.

At T=0
a= Asin(wt-kx)  = -Asin(kx),

b= -Asin(wt+kx) = -Asin(kx)

Y= a+b = -2Asin(kx)

Comment: Please write your equations using MathJax, as it is very hard to read as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

The incident wave is $\psi_1(x,t) = A \sin(\omega t-kx)$.

Now, the reflected wave has to travel in the opposite direction (hence, $\omega/k$ must have the opposite sign for the reflected wave), and the total amplitude has to be zero at the fixed end at $x=0$.

Suppose, the reflected wave is $\psi_2(x,t) = B \sin(\omega t + k x + \phi)$.

Due to the second condition, $\psi_1 + \psi_2 = 0$ at $x = 0$ for every value of $t$.

In other words, $A \sin(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t + \phi) = 0$ for every value of $t$.

The left hand side simplifies to $(A+B \cos\phi)\sin(\omega t) + B\sin(\phi) \cos(\omega t)$.

Since this quantity is zero for every value of $t$, we must have $(A+B \cos\phi) = 0$ and $B \sin\phi=0$.

The solution is either of the following -

1. $\phi = (2n + 1)\pi$ (where $n$ is an integer), and $B=A$,
2. $\phi = 2n\pi$ (where $n$ is an integer), and $B=-A$,

Both the solutions produce identical results for $\psi_2$.
Substituting the values of $B$ and $\phi$, we obtain, $\boxed{\psi_2 = -A\sin(\omega t + kx)}$.